# Form with OLE control is unable to receive focus properly

Tags: focus, ole, behavior, visual-foxpro

I have a form, which has 2 checkboxes, one of them is Ole Control : 
[image]

Now, if I call them twice, there will be 2 instances of the form, the problem is :

- Says the focus is now on form `1`, and I click on the Ole Control (checkbox), I then can't click on form `2`, meaning form 2 couldn't receive focus even I tried clicking many times on the form
- Now, if I want to get focus of the other form, I'll have to click on the title bar or the `ole control` of the form
- This won't happen if I don't click on the `Ole Control` of the form
- If I set form.Desktop = .f., everything is fine, but I need `desktop` property to be true

[image]

EDIT : Here is the `OLE` control : 
[image]

It's very simple to reproduce the error :

- Create a blank form, set `form.Desktop = .t.`, name it formOLE
- insert an OLE checkbox, like the image above
- insert a normal fox checkbox
- Call the form twice `do form formOLE`

Comment: Have you used the Event Tracker to see what events are firing, to help you understand where it's going wrong?

Comment: @TamarE.Granor and sorry for the late respond!

Comment: Since there are countless ActiveX controls, and some work well inside a VFP `Form` and some do not, can you provide more details, some repro code perhaps or at least the `OleClass` property content?

Comment: @StefanWuebbe My bad, I edited the question, please take a look at it, thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OCX on foxpro forms it should be always the last remedy. 
You are not the only one than can't access foxpro controls after a OCX control has got the focus. These are some solutions I've done throughout my projects:

- Call a very small form just for readjust the foxpro focus, a form that on activate event there is a thisform.relase. This is called after use OCX. it is common issue to not be able to edit a text field after a OCX focus.
- use OCX's visible properties

I recommend to use OCX on modal forms, if not, forms can be unaccessible.

Comment: I think this is a bug that will never get fixed by MS. Anyway thanks for the solutions, I'll check them out